# Start page load while closing animations

Tags: javascript

Question: With Javascript, can you tell the web browser to begin loading a page, but don't begin rendering it yet?

Issue: A client wants his web page to show listings like a book. When you click on the next button, he doesn't want the next page to immediately load. He wants the book to close (a closing animation) and then load the next page.

Current status: All links go to Javascript. I show the closing animation. Then, I replace the window location. The issue is that there is a clear wait for the next page to load. It would be nice if I could load the following page into cache while the closing animation runs. In other words, I want to make that three-second animation useful time by loading all the HTML, CSS, Javascript, and images for the following page and then all that happens when I set the new location is that it renders.

Possible solution: I have the main page that had two full-screen iframes in it. One iframe is the current page. The other is hidden and is used to load the next page. After the animation, I flip which iframs is visible and which isn't. This is good except that the back button doesn't work properly. If you click back, you go to wherever you were before you went to the website. You don't hide the current iframe and show the one you just hid. If you click back twice, flipping iframes doesn't work. I have to keep a log of your history. Further, I have to hack the back button, which I don't like. So, I'd like to use a built-in cache method if I can.

Comment: Set document.location to an address with an anchor e.g. yoursite.com/index.html#page3. Using this (or any) method you will still have to "hack" the back button a little bit, e.g. you will have to parse the document location in order to learn which #anchor the user has navigated to, and flip to that page. In other words there is really no way to automatically get this behavior from the back button using Javascript-based navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***Possible solution:** I have the main page that had two full-screen iframes in it. One iframe is the current page. The other is hidden and
> is used to load the next page. After the animation, I flip which iframes is visible and which isn't.*

Yes, this sounds like a good approach.

> *This is good except that the back button doesn't work properly. [...]*
> *I have to hack the back button, which I don't like.*

**Single Page Applications** (**SPAs**) can't use the back button as originally intended because the entire application exists within a single document.

Partly in response to this, we have

```
history.pushState()
```

which is a really good extension to the `History API`, enabling new "artificial" entries (describing new states) to be added to the browser's `history`, which, in turn, enables the back button to work exactly as the user might expect it to.

---

**Further Reading:**

- http://html5doctor.com/history-api/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState

Comment: Thanks. I have to take the kids shopping, but I'm going to read about pushState when I return home to see if it will solve the back button problem and give me a fully functional solution to this silly design.

Comment: I would never recommend iframes, use ajax to load the new content and js to trigger the updates. If this is a little to complicated ,there are scripts you can use like smoothstate.js. it will also handle the pushstate updates

Comment: I broadly agree, but I think when teaching oneself how to include content dynamically, `<iframe>` can be an adequate approach to begin with and `Ajax` or `Fetch API` can then represent a more sophisticated approach to graduate towards. Mastering easier but less optimal approaches is a rung on the ladder towards more complex, state-of-the-art approaches.